# How to access member variables in Swift

Tags: uiview, uitextview, swift

Behold:

```
class CatView : UIView {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView

}
```

Behold further:

```
self.myCatView.textView.text = "meow"
```

I get this error:

```
CatView? does not have a member named textView
```

To me, it seems like CatView does have a member named textView. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myCatView` must be declared as Optional in your class definition -- this is the error you get when you're trying to access a property of an Optional variable. You need to unwrap it first:

```
if let catView = self.myCatView {
    catView.textView.text = "meow"
}
```

or

```
self.myCatView!.textView.text = "meow"
```

if you're absolutely sure `self.myCatView` has a value.

Comment: It's not recommended to force unwrap optionals, unless you are really sure it's not nil. Otherwise an exception gets thrown at runtime.